# Trying to optimize a subquery in Postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been working on this query for a while now and I've finally gotten it to produce the results I want.  However, it is taking a long time to run.  I was hoping there were some optimization tips to make it run a little faster?

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 (
SELECT testschedule."asset_id" as asset_id, 
testschedule."test_id" as    test_id,
testresult."id" as testresult_id, 
testschedule."testtaken", 
testresult."testdate" as testdate,
testschedule."testdate" as scheduledate, 
verify."testresult_id" as scheduleresult_id, 
testschedule."testresult_id" as rankidtest,

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
testschedule."asset_id",  testschedule."test_id", 
testschedule."testdate" 

ORDER BY testresult."testdate" ASC) as ranking

FROM
                    "public"."testresult" testresult 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."testschedule" testschedule 
ON
testschedule."asset_id" = testresult."asset_id" 
and testschedule."test_id" = testresult."test_id"

   LEFT OUTER JOIN
               (SELECT testschedule."testresult_id",  
      testschedule."asset_id" 
      as asset_id, 
      testschedule."test_id" as test_id from
      "public"."testschedule" testschedule

    where 
      testschedule."client_id" = 25368272
      and testschedule."testdate" > '2016-06-01' 
      and testschedule."testdate" < '2016-10-20' ) verify 
    ON verify."testresult_id" = testresult."id" 
      and verify."test_id" = testschedule."test_id" and
      verify."asset_id" = testschedule."asset_id"

 WHERE

     testschedule."client_id" = 25368272

     and testresult."testdate" > 
     testschedule."maxtolerancedate" 
     and testresult."testdate" > '2016-06-01'
     and testschedule."testdate" > '2016-06-01' 
     and testschedule."testdate" < '2016-10-20'
   ) rank
 ON rank.asset_id = asset."id"
   and rank.test_id = test."id"
   and testschedule."testdate" = rank.scheduledate
   and rank.ranking = 1
```

Currently this runs in about 39 seconds for 20900 plus rows (varies per client).  That's a little longer that I would like obviously. The sub query within the "rank" sub query with the alias "verify" is there to link the correct testchedule."testresult_id" to go along with the 1st row number for testresult."testdate". Is there an obvious fix that I am missing?

Comment: Please add the query plan to the question

Comment: Pliease add the table definitions, including PK/FK to the question. And simplify/clean up your query. (the first `LEFT JOIN` decays into a plain join, because its results are referenced in the WHERE clause. Also you dont need the subquery in the second left join.